# Switch between multiple database in PDO

Tags: php

I'm new to PDO. I would like to know if there is anything similar to mysql_select_db in PDO, so that i can switch between different databases during runtime without the need for creating a new object.

Comment: Just create multiple PDO objects, each has it's own connection.

Comment: Just use the USE statement. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705195/how-do-i-select-a-mysql-database-to-use-with-pdo-in-php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is not, you will need to create two PDO objects for the separate connections if you would like to use both at runtime.

Edit: Interesting point by @laz below (which I'm guessing is the cause of negative votes on my answer). I was thinking under the assumption that the databases were on separate servers tbh, in which case my answer stands.

Answer (score 32):

I know that I am a couple of months late but you should be able to switch between databases from within your query.

examples:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbname.tablename";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM anotherdbname.anothertablename"
```

So even if your original $pdo object was used 'blahblah' as the dbname, you should still be okay based on the select examples I provided.

Comment: Of course that does not work if you have a database account which has only rights to use one database. And a lot of accounts have this for security reasons. I made a simple switch witch checks what database you want to use when calling the class and when you call for example db1 it gets the account information form a config file.

Comment: Also, this is not necessarily safe to use for inserting or updating when you're using replication.

Comment: doesn this switch between *schemas* and not *databases*?

Comment: Throws "Base table or view not found" the error message shows "connection_Initiated_DataBase.attempted_To_Switch_To_Database.table"...  it implies that the PDO connection always expects you to be with the same database after initializing the connection.

Comment: @FrankConry "database" is another name for "schema" -- the terms are usually equivalent and interchangeable, though "schema" might be more technically specific and correct.

Comment: @AaronWallentine Not true. In MySQL (at least last I used it) they were equivilant but in a normal RDMS they are not. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323740/difference-between-database-and-schema

Answer (score 23):

It looks like PDO does not have database switching because not every database engine supports it.

AFAIK PostgreSQL does not have database switching, but offer schemas and u can switch between those.

However if you're using mysql check if this works for you:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=db1;host=127.0.0.1','user','pass');

$sql = 'select count(*) from table_name';

$res = $pdo->query($sql);
print_r($res->fetchAll());

$pdo->exec('USE db2');

$res = $pdo->query($sql);
print_r($res->fetchAll());
```

Comment: I can confirm this will work in MySQL, provided the user connected has privileges to the new database.

Answer (score 10):

You actually do not need to specify the database upon connection at all. As long as you specify the database in every query, as Laz stated, this will work:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1','USER','PASS');

$query = "SELECT * FROM database1.table1";
$query = "SELECT * FROM database2.table1";
```

Comment: this throws "No Database Selected"  with the query "SELECT * FROM `database.table`"

Comment: Found this answer to not be true in my case.  `SELECT * FROM database1.table1`, results in error "No database selected".

Answer (score 6):

you don't even need to specify the database in every query, just use msyql syntax

```
 USE db_name
```

and then write your requests

Comment: I also had trouble with this approach using PDO ... would get an error #2014, "Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active."  Even though I had used fetchAll() and/or closed the cursor on all my other queries.  I ended up having to use the approach of having separate PDO instances for each DB/schema, then it worked perfectly.

Comment: This works in code for me, when leaving `dbname=xxx;` out of the PDO initializer.

Answer (score 0):

you can make this :

```php
$database1 = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db1;charset=utf8;",$username, $password);
$database2 = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db2;charset=utf8;",$username, $password);
```

simple