# PHP single method for connecting to multiple databases

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My question is given the following code how can I use a single method to connect to multiple databases?

Array of config settings:

```
$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
'mysql' => array(
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'db' => array(
        'db1' => 'database1',
        'db2' => 'database2'
    )
)
```

Connect to database:

```
private function __construct() {
    try {
        $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db/db1'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

So instead of hard coding db1 into the connection:

```
dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db/db1')
```

How to not specify a specific database here but allow for one to be called for later? I am trying to make a reusable class that can connect to any databases that are added to the config array.

Comment: What are you asking exactly, how to connect to multiple databases or how to leave a connection open?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch between multiple database in PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588775/switch-between-multiple-database-in-pdo)

Answer (score 2):

PDO doesn't provide functionality for switching databases.

You can still run a query against another database by prefixing the database to the table name, assuming the same user has access to it.

```
$pdo->query('SELECT * FROM database2.table');
```

You can also execute the use statement as confirmed here: [Switch between multiple database in PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588775/switch-between-multiple-database-in-pdo)

```
$pdo->exec('USE database2');
$pdo->query('SELECT * FROM table');
```

Comment: I'd advise against the using `USE` as you'll end up needing to use it every time just to make sure you're using the correct one. You can also create multiple PDO objects.

Comment: I agree with that.  Prefixing (or multiple objects) is definitely the better solution.  It also would be the only way if you have a query that goes across two databases.

Answer (score 2):

You could create multiple pdo connections:

```
private function __construct() {
    try {
        $this->_pdo1 = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db/db1'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
        $this->_pdo2 = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db/db2'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

This is pretty good for sharding as what might start out as different schema's might become different servers.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I think your response is an answer closest to what I was looking for. I just wonder if there will be trouble down the road with this approach is if there are many databases:

Comment: Presumably you need to manage which connections point at which schemas anyway. You could make an abstract for a single PDO manager, extend that into Singletons for each DB, then use a static factory to create or retrieve the Singletons.